# Writing at array index only works for last task in queue

Tags: opencl

I have a simple kernel like this:

```
__kernel void cycle(__global int * grid, int idx) {
    grid[idx] = idx;
}
```

and I run `clEnqueueTask()` inside a loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int arg = i;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_id, 1, &arg);
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

The expected result is an array of `[0 ...size - 1]` but it only sets the **last index** at the appropriate value. The other ones remain default (in my case 0).

I tried accumulating the value of the `idx` parameter in the first cell of the array (`grid[0] += idx`) and it gave me the expected sum of integers from `1` to `size - 1`, so the parameter gets passed correctly and the tasks are executed properly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I ended up using `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` which works well. Still not sure why task parallelism didn't work in this instance. `clEnqueueTask` is marked as deprecated on OpenCL implemented by Intel, but I'm not sure that has anything to do with the problem

Answer (score 1):

A possible suggestion to the cause of your issue:

The `arg` integer has the same memory address during the full loop; when passing it to the CL kernel, you're passing the address (instead of a copy of the value), and thus the value changes each time for all instances.

This would suggest, though, that all grid array values are equal to the same, last, value, not zero except for the last.

Why would this work when calculating the sum, though?
My guess here is that you don't store individual values inside the `grid` array (which need to be retained after the kernel finishes and data is read back); instead, the value is added and assigned to `grid[0]`, and the value in `grid[0]` doesn't rely on `idx` any further.

Admittedly, this is somewhat vague and involves some guesswork, but here's something you can try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
    *arg = i;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_id, 1, arg, sizeof(*arg));
    clEnqueueTask(command_queue, kernel_id, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

(For some reason, your example does not have the `size` argument to `clSetKernelArg`; not sure why.)
Obviously, normally you'd allocate `arg` as an array of size `size`, instead of mallocing it each iteration, but let's keep the example contrived.

If this works, you could play around to see at what point you can `free` `arg`, because the above is quite a memory leak. And I doubt you can free `arg` inside the loop.